# Summary em classes e métodos

Tags: c#, .net, documentação, summary

Qual a importância da utilização do `<summary>` em métodos e classes?

Quão impactante isso é a nível de desenvolvimento?

Qual o lado bom e qual o lado ruim da sua utilização?

Answer (score 2):

> Qual a importância da utilização do `<summary>` em métodos e classes?

Não apenas documentar seus elementos de código, mas também servir como ajuda ao utilizar o IntelliSense (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Espaço</kbd>, a descrição de `<summary>` aparece ali).

`<summary>` é apenas uma das *tags* que podem ser usadas para documentação. [Aqui tem uma lista de outras tags que podem ser usadas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx).

> Quão impactante isso é a nível de desenvolvimento?

Ajuda muito, essencialmente se você está escrevendo um componente que é comum a várias classes de seu sistema, como DLL's, por exemplo.

> Qual o lado bom e qual o lado ruim da sua utilização?

Não sei se existe lado ruim. Existe, sim, muitos lados bons.

É uma forma organizada e padronizada de documentação, que é usada tanto pelo programador quanto pela IDE. Se bem estruturada, [pode até ser usada para gerar documentação automática do seu código](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB).